# MediaRecorder.prepare() keeps failing and throwing an exception

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I have the following function below for my start record button to record audio on my Samsung S20 FE:

```
private fun startRecording (button: Button) {
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)

            setOutputFile("/Internal storage/recorded/asdf.mp4")
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)

            try {
                prepare()
                start()
                button.setText("mic started")
            } catch (er: IllegalStateException) {
                button.setText("IllegalStateException")
                er.printStackTrace()


            } catch (e: IOException) {
                //System.exit(0)
                button.setText("prepare failed")
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "media recorder prepare() failed")
            }


        }
    }
```

This function works up until the prepare() part, at which point it throws an exception and fails (I'm currently using the button to debug).

I've looked online, and people keep saying that AndroidManifest.xml must be missing the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

But mine xml file has those permissions. What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

have you also requested runtime permissions?

```
private fun requestPermission(){
 val hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMSSION_GRANTED

if(!hasPermission){
val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()){ permitted -> 
     if(!permitted){
       }
}
}
requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
}
}
```

also have a look at [this article](https://tutorials.tinyappco.com/Kotlin/MediaRecorder)

EDIT

try this snippet

```
 private MediaRecorder rec;
       String file_path=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath();

            File file= new File(file_path);

            Long date=new Date().getTime();
            Date current_time = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));

            rec=new MediaRecorder();

            rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            rec.setAudioChannels(1);
            rec.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
            rec.setAudioEncodingBitRate(44100);
            rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

            if (!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            String file_name=file+"/"+current_time+".3gp";
            rec.setOutputFile(file_name);

         try {
                    rec.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Recording_Service.this,"Sorry! file creation failed!"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                rec.start();

           rec.stop();
           rec.reset();
```

Comment: I tried using this for my permissions, but the prepare still failed. Do you have an idea of how I might set my file path up, because  the path for ```Environment.getExternalFileDir().absolutePath``` does not exist on my phone.

Comment: It just crashes when I try that new portion.

Comment: Nevermind, that link you sent to that article helped me fix it. Thanks!